# How do I override the standard SAPUI5 form CSS classes?

Tags: css, sapui5

I couldn't remove the padding, I have tried `class="sapUiNoMarginBottom"` etc.. but the class is being ignored.

```
<f:Form id="formNumberOfOptions" editable="true">
  <f:layout>
    <f:ResponsiveGridLayout/>
  </f:layout>
  <f:formContainers >
     <!-- Question -->
     <f:FormContainer>
        <f:formElements>
            <f:FormElement label="Number of Options">
                <f:fields>
                    <Input value="3" id="__numberOfOptions" width="10%"/>
                </f:fields>
            </f:FormElement>
        </f:formElements>
    </f:FormContainer>
  </f:formContainers>
</f:Form>
```

Comment: put a screenshot and show where exactly to remove the padding.

Comment: sapUiNoMarginBottom removes the margin, not the padding.

Comment: You can try `sapUiNoContentPadding`